# Why can't you get the length of (,,)?

Tags: haskell

```
length (1,2)
```

returns a result, but

```
length (1, 2, 3)
```

gives an error. Why is that?

Reading the types of `(,)` and `(,,)` did not help.

Edit: I'm thinking of the length from `Data.Foldable` `length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a consequence of the FTP [(Foldable-Traversable in Prelude)](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldable_Traversable_In_Prelude) proposal.

With that, `length` is now defined for anything that is Foldable, and it turns out there is a Foldable instance for pairs:

```
ghci> :i (,)
data (,) a b = (,) a b  -- Defined in ‘GHC.Tuple’
...
instance Monoid a => Applicative ((,) a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Foldable ((,) a) -- Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’
instance Traversable ((,) a) -- Defined in ‘Data.Traversable’
...
```

`length (a,b)` will always return 1.

There is no Foldable instance defined for tuples of higher order. For instance, if you check the classes defined for triples:

```
ghci> :i (,,)
data (,,) a b c = (,,) a b c    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Tuple’
instance (Bounded a, Bounded b, Bounded c) => Bounded (a, b, c)
instance (Eq a, Eq b, Eq c) => Eq (a, b, c)
instance (Ord a, Ord b, Ord c) => Ord (a, b, c)
instance (Read a, Read b, Read c) => Read (a, b, c)
instance (Show a, Show b, Show c) => Show (a, b, c)
instance (Monoid a, Monoid b, Monoid c) => Monoid (a, b, c)
```

you don't see a Foldable or Traversable instance, and that's why `length` isn't defined for those values.

**Update**

So `(a,b)` is considered to be a container of the single value `b`.

You can see this by observing the output of this code:

```
import Data.Foldable (fold)
import Data.Monod

foo :: Sum Int
foo = fold (3,4) :: Sum Int
```

Evaluating `foo` returns `Sum {getSum = 4}`.

Comment: And if I understand correctly the length is one because the first element in the pair is considered part of the structure of the foldable in some way so it really only has one element, namely the last?

Comment: Yes - the second element is considered to be contained value. I'll add something about this in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

The `Functor`, `Traversable`, and most especially `Foldable` instances for pairs are somewhat controversial. There are circumstances where they allow code to compile and do something that was not intended. I [proposed adding the missing functor instances for triples, etc.](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2016-January/026579.html) and, as the ensuing threads show, that really touched a nerve. So *why* doesn't `(,,)` have a `Foldable` instance? Because the community hasn't reached a consensus that it should.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting link from that thread: http://bitemyapp.com/posts/2015-10-19-either-is-not-arbitrary.html

Comment: @TheUnfunCat, oh, I know. There's no question that there is precisely one law-abiding option for `Functor` and `Traversable`. The main trouble is `Foldable`, which is a bit "wild". `length` and `null`, for instance, will work on a `Foldable` whether or not it's actually the `Foldable` you intend to be using them on. This can make wrong code compile.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, because there isn't a function named `length` that takes (,,) as input.

There is a function `length` which takes a Foldable as input: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:length

If you type this in ghci:

```
:i (,)
```

You notice it is an instance of Foldable

```
(,,)
```

is not an instance of foldable.

Comment: Ah, I did not know `:t` did not give info about typeclasses. Thanks.